# Change the color of cells which are equal to a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a range and find values that are equal to the element in cell `C3`. Then, I need to change their color. I have this piece of code that only generates random values in this range. What changes do I need to make for this to work?

```vb
Public Sub Random()

    With Range("A2:C24")
        .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(5,50)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA for this, you can do it with conditional formatting. I'd suggest looking that phrase up and going from there.

Comment: As @paxdiablo - this is easy with conditional formatting.  So is it a case of you're just trying to do it in VBA to learn, or do you need a solution to use? - in which case use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Random Range Conditional Formatting

- Change the values in the constants section as you see fit.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Random()
    Const strRange As String = "A2:C24"   ' Target Range Address
    Const strCrit As String = "C3"        ' Criteria Cell Address
    Const strFormula As String = "=RANDBETWEEN(5,20)"   ' Formula
    Const lngColor As Long = 6            ' ColorIndex (e.g. 6 - Yellow)

    Dim Cell As Variant   ' Current Cell (For Each Control Variable)
    Dim lngCrit As Long   ' Criteria Value

    ' In Target Range ...
    With Range(strRange)
        ' ... "apply" formula.
        .Formula = strFormula
        ' ... "replace" formula with values.
        .Value = .Value
        ' ... "clear" previous colors.
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End With

    ' Assign value of Criteria Cell to Criteria Value.
    lngCrit = Range(strCrit).Value

    ' Loop through cells of Target Range.
    For Each Cell In Range(strRange)
        ' Check if value of Current Cell is equal to Criteria Value.
        If Cell.Value = lngCrit Then
            ' Change color of Current Cell.
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = lngColor
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```